# Chrome downloads random files from Youtube

Tags: youtube

When I go to Youtube, on the home page, Chrome always makes me download this file called "frame". When I watch a video, there is this other file for download. When I scroll to the comments section, sometimes a download of the file "comments" pops up. Occasionally, Chrome asks me if I want to terminate all new downloads because there are too many files to download (from Youtube). These files are extensionless.

I don't know what's going on. Why is there a file called "frame" that you can download when going on Youtube? When I watch videos, it's very annoying when there is always this file for download. This doesn't happen on any other browser that I use, or any other computer.

Here is a picture showing the download of the file "frame" when I watch a random video:

[image: Chrome download]

Comment: What Chrome extensions are you running, if any?

Comment: +1 coins, Adblock, Kaspersky Anti-Banner, Kaspersky Content Blocker, Google Docs, Google Translate, Google IBA Opt-Out, Google Keep My Opt-Outs, Looper for Youtube, Magic Actions for Youtube, Netbeans Connector, New Tab Plus, Kaspersky Password Manager Plugin, Google RSS Subscription Extension, Kaspersky Safe Money, Search Engine Security, Useful Periodic Table (App), and Kaspersky Virtual Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are some solutions provided on the [support page of Chrome](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/h5jc8D56Vas), some of them work for some users but not for all but you can try them,

a user posted this solution
`Settings > History > Clear Browsing Data >

(the beginning of time)

Clear browsing history

Clear download history

Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data

Empty the cache`

another highest voted answer is

`1. Sign in on Youtube

2. Click on your user profile (icon/name)

3. Go to Youtube settings

4. Choose temporarily disconnect Google account`

If nothing works I'll recommend you to uninstall the Google Chrome and install it again after a reboot and see if that helps.

Comment: The "frame" download is now gone, but not the rest (like "comments"). Also, I lost all my browsing history and login information, which just makes browsing life harder. New problems arose after using this solution. I also have a Java problem, so I will reinstall Chrome. Thanks for providing an answer, though.

Comment: Then I can say for sure its the chrome problem, just try with a new installation may be it could take out you from that pain.